ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists error when I open my popup 5 or 9 times
when trying to open my popup, it works 5 times. and other times it works 9 times. After that this error message shows up: ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists.
class MyPopup(Popup):
    def __init__(self, title='', data='', **kwargs):
        super(MyPopup, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.title = title
        self.size_hint = (None, None)
        self.size = (700, 600)  # Set the size as needed
        self.auto_dismiss = True  # Close popup when clicking outside
        self.content = Label(text=str(data))
        self.data=str(data)
        self.ids.popup_label.text = str(data) 
        
    def on_open(self, *args):  # Add a self argument here
        # When the popup is opened, display the database information
        for item in self.data:
            self.ids.popup_label.text += str(item) + "\n"

    def on_dismiss(self):
        # Remove the popup from the list when it is dismissed
        if self in App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('third').popups:
            App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('third').popups.remove(self)

(My popup class)
class ThirdWindow(Screen):

    db_handler = DatabaseHandler()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ThirdWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.popups = []

    def display_database_info(self, query):
        cursor = self.db_handler.conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query)
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.close()
        return results
    
    def on_release(self, instance):  # Assuming this is called when a button is pressed
        query = f"SELECT * FROM {instance.text}"  # Get query based on button text
        results = self.display_database_info(query)
        popup = Factory.MyPopup(title=instance.text, data=results).open()  # Pass data argument
        self.popups.append(popup)
        popup.open()

(my third window class in which popups opens)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
